# Filter only applied if in the same package

Tags: validation, jax-rs, java-ee-7

For a Java EE application I created a custom `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter` as kindly documented by [Abhishek](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/validate-jax-rs-query-parameters/). It basically is running fine. However, when I move the annotation and filter (e.g. from `com.foo.resources`) to another package on the same level (e.g. `com.foo.filters`) then the filter is not applied anymore. *Why not?*

It does work if the filter and annotation are moved to a sub-package (e.g. from `com.foo.resources.filters`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using some package scanning for your application configuration, and you have `com.foo.resources` listed as the package to scan. With this package and all sub-packages recursively for all your `@Path` and `@Provider` classes, then register them. If you want to use multiple packages then you should be able to list both of them, delimited by a comma. I would suggest instead to just use `com.foo`, the common parent package, as it will scan the package recursively.

Comment: Thanks, it is configured in web.xml for init-param `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` of the REST-Servlet.